# add item to observable array in viewmodel from another partial view (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am new to knockoutJS. I am working on an MVC application where I want to implement knockoutJS but the scenario is bit different.

I have a page where I am showing a list. I have 3 links on the page and on click of them I am adding partial views to page accordingly. What I want to do is that whenever I add values/data to partial views, the list which is on page should be updated with knockout. In other words I want to add value to observable array when I save data from partial view.

Please let me know if this is possible or I should keep it in jquery only.

Here is the code:

Main view:

```
<input type="button" value="Add Partial View" onclick="LoadPartial();" />
<div id="dvContent"></div>
<h4>People</h4>
<ul data-bind="foreach: people">
<li>
    Name at position <span data-bind="text: $index"> </span>:
    <span data-bind="text: name"> </span>
    <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removePerson">Remove</a>
</li>
</ul>
<button data-bind="click: addPerson">Add</button>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script>
function LoadPartial() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/home/index",
        dataType:"html",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#dvContent").html(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
<script>

function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.people = ko.observableArray([
        { name: 'Bert' },
        { name: 'Charles' },
        { name: 'Denise' }
    ]);

    self.addPerson = function () {
        self.people.push({ name: "New at " + new Date() });
    };

    self.removePerson = function () {
        self.people.remove(this);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());

</script>
```

Partial View:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Add new Row</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Add" data-bind="click: addPerson"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks,
JsHunjan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to accomplish with Knockout.  You need to show some code that you have tried though if you want to get some help.  I will post a general answer but it isn't going to fix your use case exactly, just basically -

Create an object to hold your new item, you can do this either in the parent or the child view model, but if you do it in the child you need to pass it back to the parent.

Once you hit a save button or add or whatever in the child view model just do a .push() into the observableArray that you created ex... - myObservableArray.push(newItem());

Knockout will recognize all of the changes taking place and perform the actions you want automatically.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem with your logic is that the partial view is not bound to data in anyway.  Have you considered having it as a hidden aspect of your page or using a modal, so that you can bind the data properly instead of instantiating an unbound view afterwards?

Comment: can you please give me an idea how I can do that?

Comment: I got your point related to hidden model. I have done that and everything works fine now. Thanks for suggestion.